# Migrate data from MariaDB to SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, mariadb

We are planning to migrate all the data from MariaDB to SQLServer. Can anyone please suggest any approach to migrate the data so that no downtime is required as well as no data is lost.

In context of that, I have gone through a few posts here, but did not get much idea.

Comment: This is potentially a very large task, assuming your MariaDB tables might have things like triggers, etc.  If you can find a migration tool, then use it, otherwise, you will have to do things step by step.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks for your response. As of now, we don't have any triggers. We did not find any migration tool for this purpose. It would be of great help, if you give some pointers.

Comment: check this article might help: https://www.easyfrom.net/articles/mariadb_to_sql_server/

Answer (score 0):

You could look into SQL Server Integration Services functionality for migrating your data.

Or you could manually create a migration script using a linked server in your new SQL Server instance.

Or you could use BCP to perform bulk imports (which is quite fast, but requires intermediate steps to put the data in text files).

What's more important is how you want to realize the "no downtime" requirement. I suppose the migration routines need some functional requirement, which might be difficult to implement with a general migration tool, like:

- the possibility to perform the migration in multiple batches/runs (where already migrated data is skipped), and
- the possibility to implement different phases of the migration in different solutions, like bulk imports (using text files and staging tables) for history data (which will not change anymore), but live queries over a live database connection for the latest updates in the MariaDB/MySQL database.

The migration strategy might also largely depend on the size of the data in MariaDB/MySQL, and the structure of the database(s) and its data. Perhaps you want to keep auto-generated primary key values, because the system requires them to remain unchanged. Perhaps you need to use different data types for some exotic table fields. Perhaps you need to re-implement some database logic (like stored procedures and functions). Etc. etc.

It is very difficult to give some ad-hoc advice about these kind of migration projects; as Tim Biegeleisen already commented, this can be quite a complex job, even for "small" databases. It practically always requires a lot of research, extensive preparations, test runs (in a testing environment using database backups), some more test runs, a final test run, etc. And - of course - some analytics, metrics, logging, and reporting for troubleshooting (and to know what to expect during the actual migration). If the migration will be long-running, you want to make sure it does not freeze the live production environment, and you might also want some form of progress indication during the migration.

And - last but not least - you surely want to have a "plan B" or a quick return strategy in case the actual migration will fail (despite all those careful preparations).

Hope I did not forget something... ;-)